# Wrapping a string in C with a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to create a function `guilabel_wrap(char *buffer, int maxlen)` that takes a pointer to a string and a length, then modifies the string to insert \n so that the string never exceeds the length, such that

```
char* guilabel = "Hello, world! How are you doing?";
guilabel_wrap(guilabel, 15);
printf("%s", guilabel);
```

will print

```
Hello, world!
How are you
doing?
```

I've come up with the function below, which compiles with gcc, but results in a segmentation fault. I suspect that the issue is with the 2nd while loop and a failure of my understanding of pointers.

```
void guilabel_wrap(char* buffer, int maxlen) {
    char *pos;
    char *end;
    pos = buffer;
    end = (pos + strlen(buffer));

    while ((end - pos) > maxlen) {
        pos += maxlen;
        while (isspace(*pos)) {
            --pos;
            if (pos < buffer)
                return;
        }
    *pos = '\n';
    }
}
```

edit: I'm calling this function using an argument from another function. It looks like this:

```
dia_yesno("Hello, world! How are you doing today? I'm doing well");
```

which is declared as `bool dia_yesno(char* guilabel)`. Then, within `dia_yesno()`, I call `guilabel_wrap(guilabel, 15)` as described above.

Comment: You should run this in a debugger, to locate the exact line and loop iteration that causes the seg-fault.

Comment: Why are you calling `printf(*guilabel)`? What you're looking for is `puts(guilabel)` or `printf("%s\n",guilabel)`.

Comment: I'm not actually using printf(); I added that for demonstration purposes (and had a typo--how embarassing!). This pointer is given to this function from its parent. I've edited my question to reflect this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string constant is probably in a read-only area of memory, which is why you are getting the segmentation fault. This can be demonstrated by trying to run the following code:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* str = "foo";
    str[0] = 'b';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo
Bus error: 10
```

You should create a buffer large enough to hold your string, plus the additional `'\n'` characters, and copy your string into that first. Declaring your string as an array will also fix the problem, such as:

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[16] = "foo";
    str[0] = 'b';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo
boo
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string should be made like this:

```
 char guilabel[64] = "my string here";
```

And you should write the string using a format to printf:

```
printf("%s\n", guilabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The string will be in the data segment of the executable and will be read-only. You will need to make a copy - use `strdup`.

Really `guilabel` should be declared as `const char *const guilabel` which represents its true type.

Comment: As far as I understand it,  it's actually not the data segment. (It'll be in the text segment, alongside the executable code.) The data segment is for writable global variables.

Comment: Oh, I guess some compilers put string constants in an `rodata` section, for read-only data. I'm pretty sure some also use the text segment, though.

Comment: Thats what I meant - knew I should have gon e to bed.